# org-mode export file to other folder while not 'pwd'

Tags: emacs, org-mode

When I use C-c C-e h o, my .org file will be converted to .html file and opened in web browser. 
But this .html file is located in pwd folder as .org file.
Is it possible to export in this way, that the .html file is located in other folder for example ~/exports/

With this method, I can separate the generated file in other folder.

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at `org-publish-project-alist`.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on osman's answer:

You can create something similar to the following:

Make sure to change `:base-directory` to match where you want the files to be sourced from.

```lisp
("org-notes"
 :base-directory "~/org/"    ;; Change this to where your files are stored.
 :base-extension "org"
 :publishing-directory "~/exports/"
 :recursive t
 :publishing-function org-publish-org-to-html
 :headline-levels 4             ; Just the default for this project.
 :auto-preamble t
 )
```

Template adjusted from [Notes section](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-publish-html-tutorial.html#sec-3-1) of the publishing tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can find the details of how to setup everything for publishing org files to html in the docs here:

http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-publish-html-tutorial.html

You can also check out the info page for the variable:

```
org-publish-project-alist
```

By invoking `C-h v` and entering its name when prompted in the minibuffer at the bottom of emacs.